# Understand 'arcane' literally

Tags: vocabulary

I read a sentence:

> This argument may seem arcane to those not closely involved in the world of finance.

In [arcane | Definition of arcane in English by Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arcane)

> Understood by few; mysterious or secret.
>   with synonyms of 'mysterious, secret, hidden, concealed, covert, clandestine, enigmatic, dark'

Is it a frequently used word in written english?

I try to understand it by referring to "`arc` `and` `e`" in mathematics which is arcane to students.

Is there a better solution to understand this word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of '*[Arcane](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/arcane)*' has significantly increased over the years (until the bimillennial), in literary materials. This **[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arcane&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carcane%3B%2Cc0)** shows the frequency of usage of '*Arcane*' from written materials, spanning from 1800 to 2008. Although the word is not that frequently used in day-to-day conversations, the word may be used somewhat commonly in historical terms and theoretical literature.

To understand the word better, why don't you look into the history and [origin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/arcane) of the word:

> 1540s, from Latin '**arcanus**' "secret, hidden, private, concealed," from '**arcere**' "to close up, enclose, contain," from arca "chest, box, place for safe-keeping," from PIE root ***ark**- "to hold, contain, guard" (source also of Greek '**arkos**' "defense," '**arkein**' "to ward off;" Armenian '**argel**' "obstacle;" Lithuanian raktas "**key**," rakinti "to shut, lock").

As per your way of learning the word, that depends on one person to another. You used this to learn the word:

> "*Referring to "arc and e" in mathematics, which is arcane to students.*"

But I wouldn't learn this word using your method, I would relate it to "[Arcanine](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Arcanine_(Pok%C3%A9mon))", which happens to be a mysterious and enigmatic Pokemon. But that's just me. The way a person learns a new word is by relating it to something he personally knows. This can be influenced by another person's thought process, but it generally comes from within you. *This part of the question is primarily opinion-based.*